# How does an application "intercept" the openURL method in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

If you have the Facebook app installed, and use the Application `openURL` method to open a Facebook page, you will notice that the Facebook app takes over and processes this URL, rather than Safari doing it.

How is that achieved for your own app?

Comment: it's called Custom URL Scheme. You can setup your own Custom URL scheme in your App's Info.plist.

Comment: each app has a url schema, based on that the os will directly open that app. safari has one schema and facebook app has another schema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you can set a custom URL scheme for your app. This is on a per app basis. For example, the facebook's app url might be something like "fb://". You can create whatever prefix you want for your URL, but be sure that it's unique (not sure what happens if there's two apps using the same prefix).

Once that's all set up, you can capture the custom URL by using the following method in your appdelegate class:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    // handler code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement Custom URL scheme in your app : Read Section "Implementing Custom URL Schemes" in the [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html).

Here are links for tutorial on this topic: [Tutorial 1](http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/custom_url_schemes.html), [Tutorial 2](https://coderwall.com/p/mtjaeq)